# Which bicycle cameras are suitable for all weather 11+ hours food delivery cyclists

Tags: safety, camera

I am a bicycle food delivery boy.

After a close pass forcing line variation followed by a threat of assault using a motor vehicle I now desire to mount cameras for evidence.

I also want to mount cameras to contribute to the mapillary project.

I require cameras that:

- Mount front rear and helmet
- Have audio for evidential purposes
- Have enough resolution for evidential purposes
- Record 11+ hours for mapillary
- Are water proof against torrential rain
- Are drop proof against normal working life on a bicycle
- Function at night for evidential purposes
- Are pit lock secureable or equivalent to the bike and helmet
- Auto delete old content so I don't have to fiddle to keep the storage ready to work

I desire cameras that:

- Have gps inbuilt
- Auto pause when not moving and auto resume when moving to conserve data and battery
- Function at night without requiring settings changes from having functioned in daylight

Comment: You'll struggle to find anything that will record for 11+ hours without it being attached to the mains. But, in any case, product recs are off-topic here.

Comment: I checked the back catalogue and in 2014 there was a commuter camera question I modelled off. Is the question save able?

Comment: It's difficult because you're basically looking for product suggestions from us. But have a look online at what cameras are available, what their limitations are, and how much they cost. Cameras are quite new technology, and battery life is somewhat limited yet.

Comment: There are front and rear cameras that continuously overwrite old data; a friend has one. I'll see what make it is. Meanwhile, check some of the "related" questions.

Comment: He tells me he has two products named Fly6 and Fly12.

Comment: @andy256 I purchased a Fly6 when they were available as a Kickstarter.  Has survived daily use a year or so in.  Have caught some interesting footage. Mainly lazy roadies trying to sneak a draft!

Comment: You'll need a camera you can run off a USB external battery if you want to use it for 11 hours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Answering because I'm not making a product suggestion.*

There aren't any.   Most of the action-style cameras go for about 2 hours on their internal battery.

Personally I have run a single gopro 3 on a 9AH external USB battery for over 12 hours, but this is vulnerable to water entering the camera housing, and the continual vibrations of riding bouncing the plugs in their sockets.

You'll also need a 64 GB memory card per shift per camera, or some way to empty them all overnight while you sleep.

Many action cameras lack datestamp functions too, so its hard to prove that events happened at a specific time/date.

Plus a camera makes your bike more of a theft target.  So if you do this consider a chest harness.

All the action cameras are poor-to-crap at night.  I know of no night-vision action cameras.

---

### *Alternatives*

Make yourself visible - that's

- multiple front and rear lights
- spread those lights around the bike (high and low positions)
- white spoke reflectors (the yellow ones are not half as good as these)
- reflective white-side tyres (not white-walls)
- high-vis top/jacket with reflective piping or panels.

Other suggestions:

- Learn where to not bike at night - narrow bridges, bad roads, anywhere the yobs/hooligans congregate..... just use another route even if its longer.
- Don't be afraid to say "We can't deliver to that address after dark"

If you're stuck on mapillory best to look at their requirements or suggested camera list.   From their website, its an app-only driven service so you're out of luck with that requirement.  Better drop this, or run your cellphone camera separately just for this service.